# Triac Switching Circuit

Tags: ac, switching, triac, load

I will switch an ac load with a triac. I am providing a dc voltage of 5V on the gate of first Triac and 0V on the gate of second Triac. In the first picture the triac is working and the switch is closed but in the second picture the triac is still closed despite providing 5V to its gate. I don't understand why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your words do not compute and it's unclear why you show two circuits or why you require two triacs in each circuit.

Comment: The voltage source that I connected to the gate, in the first picture the negative termina of the source is conneted to a common ground, but in the second picture i just connected a ground to the negative terminal. in the second picture the triac is switched off despite that %V dc source connected to its gate. Regarding the second Triac its not important. I have it switched off anyway, it was there just to check something :).

Comment: Connecting ground to negative terminal means it is connected to ground just like the bottom horizontal node therefore, you have NOT disconnected the source in the 2nd picture.

Comment: those capacitors are very small, why are they there?